# JavaScript: How to check to see if string contains value in array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of versions:

```
var versions = ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'thumbnail'];
```

I want to get all the image stored in this array that do not contain any of these suffixes. Here is an example of the array of images:

```
{
    "files": [
        "/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1.png",
        "/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1_xs.png",
        "/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1_sm.png",
        "/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1_md.png",
        "/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1_lg.png",
        "/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1_thumbnail.png"
    ]
}
```

I only want the first item, however, I am getting all of them with my current code:

```
fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
    if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
        // perform directory code here
    } else {
        versions.forEach(function(version) {
            if (file.indexOf(version) != -1) {
                results.push(file);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Is `versions` in the bottom code the same as the array called `version` at the top ?

Comment: If you just want the first item, why not stopping the forEach loop with a "return;" ?

Comment: I believe he's saying that he only wants the first item because the first filename is the only one that doesn't contain one of those suffixes in `versions`.

Comment: use some() instead of forEach() and return true to stop the iteration.

Comment: Something's wrong in the logic. Your `version.forEach` will push the file unless all the vesions occur in the filename.

Comment: My mistake, it will push unless all the versions *don't* occur in the filename. It is doing the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how i would do it :

1) take the suffix of the file. The definition i took was 'a non-numeric string between a _ and the . that precedes the 3 letters of the file format.' You might want another definition or do some checks.
But i think it' a good start to have at hand the suffix to avoid surprises if other part of file name contains a matching string.

```
// provides lower case suffix of the file, or null if none found.
function getSuffix (s) { 
         var res = /_([a-zA-Z]+)\.\w{3}$/g.exec(s) ;
         if (!res) return null;
         return res[1].toLowerCase();
}
```

2) write the available formats like this :

```
var version = { xs : true, sm : true, md : true, lg : true, thumbnail : true } ;
```

3) then checking is done with  :

```
var suffix = getSuffix(fileName) ;
if (version[suffix]) /* do something */
```

---

( Notice that this way you can easily associate a function to a format :

```
var versionProcessors = { xs : function(fileBuffer) { /* process a xs buffer */ }, 
                          sm : function(fileBuffer) ...,
                   .      .. } ;

// ... later ....
var suffix = getSuffix(fileName) ;
var processor = versionProcessors[suffix]; 
if (processor) {
      getFileBuffer(fileName, processor);
}
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this:

```
if (file.indexOf(version) == -1) {
    results.push(file);
}
```

If the filename contains the suffix, `file.indexOf(version)` will return an index > -1, so you don't want to add it to the results. However, if the filename doesn't contain the suffix, that line will return -1.

Comment: This is also wrong. Why ? it will push the filename if it contains a version and you match for another vesion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
var versions = ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'thumbnail'];
results=[];
files=[
    "/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1.png",
    "/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1_xs.png",
    "/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1_sm.png",
    "/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1_md.png",
    "/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1_lg.png",
    "/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1_thumbnail.png"
]
files.forEach(function (file){
    //start checking
    findany=false;
    versions.forEach(function(version) {
        if (file.indexOf(version) != -1) findany=true;
    });
    if(!findany) results.push(file);
    //end checking
})
```

Output

```
> results
[ '/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1.png' ]
```